# Не работает update, но $_POST с этими данными отправляется

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть форма для редактирования данных пользователя. Исходные данные в нее передаются и читаются.
Вот запрос для чтения:
`private $select_data = 'select id_reg, name_reg, password, email, tel_num, fk_con_reg, city from registr_data, contacts where id_reg = ? and id_reg=fk_con_reg';`

var_dump такой:

```
array (size=7)
  'id_reg' => string '84' (length=2)
  'name_reg' => string 'Аркадий' (length=14)
  'password' => string '$2y$10$E18G4qDaEJnDh..Z2NUEKOOKWTP67Wuy4NFXH3sVPxqV5tv3eaCPm' (length=60)
  'email' => string 'ark@yandex.ru' (length=13)
  'tel_num' => string '(33)123-45-67' (length=13)
  'fk_con_reg' => string '84' (length=2)
  'city' => string 'Витебск' (length=14)
```

Запрос для update:
`private $update_data = 'update registr_data, contacts set name_reg=?, email=?, password=?, city=?, tel_num=? where id_reg=? and id_reg=fk_con_reg';`

var_dump (чтобы поймать POST, намеренно не введен ном.телефона):

```
array (size=6)
  'id_reg' => string '84' (length=2)
  'name_reg' => string 'Аркадий' (length=14)
  'email' => string 'ark22222@yandex.ru' (length=18)
  'password' => string 'AAA111aaa' (length=9)
  'city' => string 'Минск' (length=10)
  'tel_num' => string '' (length=0)
```

Т.е. данные передаются, но в самой БД не меняются.

Код для БД:

```
public static function select($sql, $parameters = null) {
    $pdostmt = self::$pdo->prepare($sql);
    $pdostmt->execute($parameters);
    return $pdostmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public static function exec($sql, $parameters = null) {
    $pdostmt = self::$pdo->prepare($sql);
    return $pdostmt->execute($parameters);
}
```

Вот сама функция:

```
public function update()
    {
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {//проверка данных и запись в базу
            if ($this->validate()) {
                
                \Core\Db::exec($this->update_data, [htmlspecialchars($this->data['name_reg']),
                    htmlspecialchars($this->data['email']), 
                    password_hash($this->data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
                    $this->data['city'], htmlspecialchars($this->data['tel_num']), $this->data['id_reg']]);
            }
        } else {//Чтение данных для редактирования
            $user = \Model\Session::getUserId();
            $this->data['id_reg'] = $user;
            $data = \Core\Db::select($this->select_data, [$this->data['id_reg']]);
            $this->data = $data[0];
        }
    }
```

Также в функции validate() есть проверка на `if ($_POST['update'])`.

К слову, insert, delete запросы, как и select, с БД работают.
Буду благодарна любой помощи!

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Без понятия что у вас там может не работать - вы не обрабатываете то что вам возвращает PDO, не используете [errorCode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.errorcode.php) или [errorInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.errorinfo.php) - и нам остается только гадать что же именно у вас не работает.

Comment: Спасибо, я совсем новичок в php. Думаю, эти функции помогут мне разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка заключается в запросе. Смотрите синтаксис SQL.

```
UPDATE table_name SET pole_name=? WHERE pole_name=?
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но запрос как раз рабочий. Это первое, что я проверяла в самой БД. Ошибка была в функции валидации и в том, что она передавала. Ее код я не предоставляла, т.к. была уверена, что там-то точно всё ок.